# How can I write a link in smaller font on main site?

Tags: support, formatting

I am attempting to write links in smaller font.

<sub>I know how to write text in small font.</sub>

However, if I try to insert a link, it doesn't turn blue on the main site. <sub>It seem to turn blue here: https://stackoverflow.com.</sub> The place where I cannot make it work is the bottom of this post: [How to maximize weighted sum of correct classifications with Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695925/how-to-maximize-weighted-sum-of-correct-classifications-with-tensorflow). How can I make it format as link there?

If I tell it explicitly that it is a link, using text format, I get:

[image]

Comment: Would it work if you specifically tell it that it's a link using the `[]()` syntax? `[https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns)`

Comment: Thaks for the tip! Updated my post. (It doesn't...)

Comment: Wow that's weird. I'm curious now what the real answer will be.

Comment: it seems to be working for me (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662423/8620333 [the ref word]) unless I am not understanding what you mean

Comment: another example where it's fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690376/8620333

Comment: From some quick testing, it seems to only happen when the `<sub>` tag is exactly one line above the text. It works if they're on the same line or there's an empty line in between.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it @JohnMontgomery!